# At what level do leveled items stop improving?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the minimum level I need to be to get the strongest version of leveled items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37679/what-is-the-minimum-level-i-need-to-be-to-get-the-strongest-version-of-leveled-i)

From what I understand, items that are given as quest rewards are leveled items as in the stats/enchantments values are based on the level at the time which you receive that item (and they don't continue leveling as you do).  Is there a certain level at which point the item will not improve any more (like an item received at level 30 is the same power as the same item received at level 55)?

Comment: you definitely get better items at level 50 than 30, but I'd imagine the items stop improving once you start finding daedric stuff

Comment: @yx. Levelled item materials and levelled quest rewards aren't linked.

Answer (score 1):

[UESP has 46](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveled_Items) as the highest number for leveled items. [Level 48](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Armor) is where you can start finding Daedric armor.

We might not be able to tell for sure until we get the Creation Kit.

Comment: Please try to avoid posting identical answers to multiple questions, even if they are duplicate questions. Thanks!